# Recovery .py from .exe python created by cx_Freeze

Tags: python-3.x, executable, cx-freeze

I created a .exe python using cx_Freeze and it runs normally. I had a problem with my SSD e I lost my script. Is it possible get script back from some folder of lib of .exe?

Somebody has a solution of how recovery my script .py?